# Choosing SSL client certificate in Java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

Our system communicates with several web services providers. They are all invoked from a single Java client application. All the web services up until now have been over SSL, but none use client certificates. Well, a new partner is changing that.

Making the application use a certificate for the invocation is easy; setting `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` will do it. However, the problem is now how to make it so that it only uses the certificate when invoking that particular web service. I guess more generally speaking, we'd like to be able to choose the client certificate to be used, if any.

One quick solution could be setting the system properties, invoking the methods, and then unsetting them. The only problem with that is that we're dealing with a multi-threaded application, so now we would need to deal with synchronization or locks or what have you.

Each service client is supposed to be completely independent from each other, and they're individually packaged in separate JARs. Thus, one option that has occurred to me (although we haven't properly analyzed it) is to somehow isolate each JAR, maybe load each one under a different VM with different parameters. That's merely an idea that I don't know how to implement (or if it's even possible, for that matter.)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209081/get-privatekey-from-keystore) suggests that it is possible to select an individual certificate from a key store, but how to attach it to the request seems to be a different issue altogether.

We're using Java 1.5, Axis2, and client classes generated with either `wsimport` or `wsdl2java`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java SSL clients will only send a certificate if requested by the server. A server can send an optional hint about what certificates it will accept; this will help a client choose a single certificate if it has multiple.

Normally, a new `SSLContext` is created with a specific client certificate, and `Socket` instances are created from a factory obtained from that context. Unfortunately, Axis2 doesn't appear to support the use of an `SSLContext` or a custom `SocketFactory`. Its client certificate settings are global.

Comment: Unfortunately we have no control over the servers. I was also hoping that those hints could be useful, but a test showed that at least with one server they weren't. WRT Axis2, that has also been my experience. If you happen to know of another Java tool that allows this sort of behavior, I'd greatly appreciate your sharing; we'll gladly explore it.

Comment: @Carlos - Maybe I wasn't clear. You don't need any control over the server; if your partner is now requiring a client certificate, they will configure their server to request it. Your client will *not* send that certificate to any other servers, because they (presumably) are not requesting it. The only potential problem would be if additional services start requiring a client certificate, but don't accept the same CAs.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I guess the other question remains, though. If tomorrow we add another web service that also requires a client certificate, is there a way to choose which certificate in the key store to present to each service?

Comment: It looks like Axis 2 uses Apache HTTP Client 3.x underneath, so it should be possible to configure an `SSLContext` this way (although I haven't tried).

Answer (score 14):

The configuration is done via an `SSLContext`, which is effectively a factory for the `SSLSocketFactory` (or `SSLEngine`). By default, this will be configured from the `javax.net.ssl.*` properties. In addition, when a server requests a certificate, it sends a TLS/SSL `CertificateRequest` message that contains a list of CA's distinguished names that it's willing to accept. Although this list is strictly speaking only indicative (i.e. servers could accept certs from issuers not in the list or could refuse valid certs from CAs in the list), it usually works this way.

By default, the certificate chooser in the `X509KeyManager` configured within the `SSLContext` (again you normally don't have to worry about it), will pick one of the certificates that has been issued by one in the list (or can be chained to an issuer there).
That list is the `issuers` parameter in [`X509KeyManager.chooseClientAlias`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html#chooseClientAlias%28java.lang.String[],%20java.security.Principal[],%20java.net.Socket%29) (the `alias` is the alias name for the cert you want to picked, as referred to within the keystore). If you have multiple candidates, you can also use the `socket` parameter, which will get you the peer's IP address if that helps making a choice.

If this helps, you may find using [jSSLutils (and its wrapper)](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/SSLContextFactory#FixedServerAliasKeyManager) for the configuration of your `SSLContext` (these are mainly helper classes to build `SSLContext`s). (Note that this example is for choosing the server-side alias, but it can be adapted, the [source code is available](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/source/browse/tags/jsslutils-root-1.0.7/jsslutils/src/main/java/org/jsslutils/sslcontext/keymanagers/FixedServerAliasKeyManager.java).)

<strike>Once you've done this, you should look for the documentation regarding the `axis.socketSecureFactory`system property in Axis (and [`SecureSocketFactory`](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/components/net/SecureSocketFactory.html)). If you look at the Axis source code, it shouldn't be too difficult to build a `org.apache.axis.components.net.SunJSSESocketFactory` that's initialized from the `SSLContext` of your choice (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247746/java-loading-ssl-keystore-via-a-rsource/3256676#3256676)).</strike>

Just realized you were talking about Axis2, where the `SecureSocketFactory` seems to have disappeared. You might be able to find a workaround using the default `SSLContext`, but this will affect your entire application (which isn't great). If you use a [X509KeyManagerWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/SSLContextFactory#X509KeyManagerWrapper) of jSSLutils, you might be able to use the default `X509KeyManager` and treat only certain hosts as an exception. (This is not an ideal situation, I'm not sure how to use a custom `SSLContext`/`SSLSocketFactory` in Axis 2.)

Alternatively, according to [this Axis 2 document](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5/http-transport.html#httpsupport), it looks like Axis 2 uses Apache HTTP Client 3.x:

> If you want to perform SSL client
>   authentication (2-way SSL), you may
>   use the Protocol.registerProtocol
>   feature of HttpClient. You can
>   overwrite the "https" protocol, or use
>   a different protocol for your SSL
>   client authentication communications
>   if you don't want to mess with regular
>   https. Find more information at
>   http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/httpclient/sslguide.html

In this case, the [`SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory`](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/ApacheHttpClientUsage) should help you configure an `SSLContext`.

Comment: Hum... and just realized you're using Java 1.5, so no `SSLContext.setDefault(...)` anyway.  Why not use Java 6? Java 5 is no longer supported as far as I know (it would do no harm to have various security patches).

Comment: (Setting the `SSLContext` via Apache HTTP Client 3.x should work with Java 1.5.)

Comment: @Carlos, no problem. Did the change of SSLContext via Apache HTTP Client's Protocol.registerProtocol work with Axis 2 (just curious)?

Comment: Actually, no change was needed, but it was good to have those general comments and input.

Answer (score 0):

I initialized [EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/javadocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.html) and Protocol instances for different endpoints and register the protocol with unique key like this:

```
/**
 * This method does the following:
 * 1. Creates a new and unique protocol for each SSL URL that is secured by client certificate
 * 2. Bind keyStore related information to this protocol
 * 3. Registers it with HTTP Protocol object 
 * 4. Stores the local reference for this custom protocol for use during furture collect calls
 * 
 *  @throws Exception
 */
public void registerProtocolCertificate() throws Exception {
    EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory easySSLPSFactory = new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory();
    easySSLPSFactory.setKeyMaterial(createKeyMaterial());
    myProtocolPrefix = (HTTPS_PROTOCOL + uniqueCounter.incrementAndGet());
    Protocol httpsProtocol = new Protocol(myProtocolPrefix,(ProtocolSocketFactory) easySSLPSFactory, port);
    Protocol.registerProtocol(myProtocolPrefix, httpsProtocol);
    log.trace("Protocol [ "+myProtocolPrefix+" ] registered for the first time");
}

/**
 * Load keystore for CLIENT-CERT protected endpoints
 */
private KeyMaterial createKeyMaterial() throws GeneralSecurityException, Exception  {
    KeyMaterial km = null;
    char[] password = keyStorePassphrase.toCharArray();
    File f = new File(keyStoreLocation);
    if (f.exists()) {
        try {
            km = new KeyMaterial(keyStoreLocation, password);
            log.trace("Keystore location is: " + keyStoreLocation + "");
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
            if (logErrors){
                log.error("Exception occured while loading keystore from the following location: "+keyStoreLocation, gse);
                throw gse;
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.error("Unable to load Keystore from the following location: " + keyStoreLocation );
        throw new CollectorInitException("Unable to load Keystore from the following location: " + keyStoreLocation);
    }
    return km;
}
```

When I have to invoke the web service, I do this (which basically replace "https" in the URL with https1, or https2 or something else depending on the Protocol you initialized for that particular endpoint):

```
httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host, port,Protocol.getProtocol(myProtocolPrefix));
initializeHttpMethod(this.url.toString().replace(HTTPS_PROTOCOL, myProtocolPrefix));
```

It works like a charm!

Comment: Can you point the imports? EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory? KeyMaterial? A complete example with dependencies would be very nice. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you could please elaborate on your code somewhat more.

Comment: Have a look at this file on github to answer most of your questions: https://github.com/nickman/helios/blob/gh-pages/helios-collectors/collectors-http/src/main/java/org/helios/collectors/url/URLCollector.java