# SSL certificate problem in a web service proxy

Tags: java, web-services, xml-rpc, rpc

I am building a JAVA web service client in which i connect to a service.

This service has a ssl certificate verification.

How to call this service using ssl certificate verification.

I am using JAX-RPC implementation in client built using Eclipse.

An example would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to do the web service connection...

I added the key store using the command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file <file path/filename.cer> -alias <aliasName> -keystore <JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts>
```

gave the password as "changeit" and added the certificate in keystore.

Now in code i added two lines:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

also added

```
_call.setUsername("username");
_call.setPassword("password");
```

where _call is the call object of Call Class.

And it worked!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is injecting the server root certificate to your JDK/JRE environments by using the following command line: -

```
keytool -importcerts -trustcacerts -file <path_to_root_cer_file> -alias <the_server_alias> -keystore <your_keystore>
```

The default [your_keystore] is

```
 1. <JDK_HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts
 2. <JRE_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts
```

The default password is *changeit*.

When you call the web service, just mention the

```
"https://<host>:<SSL_port>/Path/To/Services"
```

I hope this may help to achieve your requirement.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 0):

You mean your web service is protected with a "client certificate"? If yes, get the certificate in either a .p12 (PFX) or keystore format from the service provider and use the following System properties to set it before your call:

**javax.net.ssl.keyStore** - Path to the keystore on your server

**javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword** - passphrase for that keystore

**javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType** - Set it to "pkcs12" is the client certificate provided to you is .p12

If you application is client to only one web service provider, set these properties as VM arguments, if not, you may need to create specific SSLConnectionFactory for each secured endpoint.  Refer to my response on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465907/creating-ssl-client-with-axis2-java/6469073#6469073) for details on creating custom SSL Socket Factories.