# Installing sbt-eclipse- unresolved dependency javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am a beginner to sbt and trying to create a project using `sbt eclipse` with the following configuration

1. Scala(v 2.12.4)
2. sbt (v 1.1.0)
3. OS (Windows)

I have created plugins directory in .sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt and added the following

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
```

I am getting the SSLHandshake exception as following

```
D:\scalaapp\eclipsetest>sbt eclipse
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: D:\scalaapp\eclipsetest
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\john\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/john/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin
/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExce
ption: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-
plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuild
erException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:5.2.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:5.2.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\john\.sbt\1.0\plugins\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- org.scala-sbt:global-plugins:0.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclip
se-plugin;5.2.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclips
e-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBui
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbt
eclipse-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertP
athBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:243)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:242)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:46)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:99)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:112)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:95)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:126)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2383)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: Resolutio
n failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclips
e-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBui
lderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.2.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbt
eclipse-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertP
athBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Do I need any additional configuration in order to avoid this exception?

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with the plugin setup, but more like a problem with access to the artifact repositories. Are you using proxy? If yes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41981320/736957) question (and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492122/736957))

Comment: You need to install SSL certificate of your network to cacerts. it is very simple to get and install follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348)