# Java ignore certificate validation

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create some sample Java projects that connect to a self-signed HTTPS server.  I can't seem to get Java to stop trying to validate the certificate.  I don't want to have to trust this certificate, I just want to ignore all certificate validation altogether; this server is inside my network and I want to be able to run some test apps without worrying about whether the certificate is valid.

```
java -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false HelloWorld
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The **-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false** didn't help.  I also tried adding the following code:

```
public static void DisableCertificateValidation() {
  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
      public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
      public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
    }
  };
  try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

But still have the same issue.  What's going on here?

Comment: have you managed to ignore certificate with axis2? Josip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault` indicates that you're using Axis 2, and Axis 2 doesn't use `HttpsURLConnection` to make its HTTP(S) connections, but Apache HttpClient (3.x as far as I know), so `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(...)` will have no effect there.

You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712366/choosing-ssl-client-certificate-in-java/3713147#3713147) about setting up an `SSLContext` for Axis 2, more specifically, this document: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#httpsupport

(Alternatively, you may be able to get away with setting the default `SSLContext` with `SSLContext.setDefault(...)`, introduced in Java 6. Disabling certificate verification for your default SSL context is obviously not a good idea in a real application.)

Comment: Ahh, so Axis2 doesn't use HttpsUrlConnection, that explains a lot!  Erm...I'm still not sure how to set up SSLContext here, sort of overwhelming amount of documentation, which I have trouble with because somehow I feel like it should be a simple switch somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, adding `SSLContext.setDefault(sc)` with the value of `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` (or `SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")`?) appears to work here.

Answer (score 4):

This is an older question but I stumbled upon it and it kinda psuhed me in the right diretion. I could access an https url in axis2 without a valid client certificate by setting the params:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol;

EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory easySSLProtocolSocketFactory;
try {
     easySSLProtocolSocketFactory = new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory();
     Protocol.unregisterProtocol("https");
     Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https",
                  (ProtocolSocketFactory) easySSLProtocolSocketFactory, 443));
}
catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just be sure to do this before calling the axis2 service client. This is nothing I would do in production, but as a fast hack for an unsecured server that did the trick for me.