# Attach client certificates with Axis2?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-axis, ssl-certificate, axis

Is it possible to easily attach a client certificate to a Axis2 stub generated using wsdl2java? I need to change the client certificate dynamically on a per-request basis, so simply storing it in the keystore won't work for our case.

I've found examples where this is being done for non-SOAP calls, but could not find anything related to using the Axis client stubs. Trying to hack the XML for the SOAP call is an option I guess, albiet a painful one! Groan!

Comment: ¿This takes into account that you need the current certificate to retrieve a message with the new certificate? Also, the WS client must be able to replace the certificate in the keystore because it can't live outside the keystore and stay accesible to java.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change which certificate is used depending on which connection is made, you'll need to configure an `SSLContext` to do so, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713147/372643

As far as I know, Axis 2 uses Apache HttpClient 3.x, so you'll need to follow its way of configuring the `SSLContext` (and `X509KeyManager` if needed).
The easiest way might be to configure Apache HttpClient's global `https` protocol handler with your `SSLContext`, set up with an `X509KeyManager` configured to choose the client certificate as you require (via `chooseClientAlias`).

If the issuers and the connected `Socket` (probably the remote address) are not enough for deciding which certificate to choose, you may need to implement a more complex logic which will almost inevitably require careful synchronization with the rest of your application.

**EDIT**:

Once you've built your `SSLContext` and `X509KeyManager`, you need to pass them to Apache HttpClient 3.x. For this, you can build your own [SecureProtocolSocketFactory](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/SecureProtocolSocketFactory.html), which will build the socket from this `SSLContext` (via an `SSLSocketFactory`, see `SSLContext` methods). There are examples in the [Apache HttpClient 3.x SSL guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html). Avoid `EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory`, since it won't check any server cert (thereby allowing for MITM attacks). You could also try [this implementation](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/source/browse/trunk/extra/apachehttpclient/src/main/java/org/jsslutils/extra/apachehttpclient/SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory.java).

Note that you only really need to customize your `X509KeyManager`, you can initialize your `SSLContext` (via `init`) with `null` for the other parameters to keep the default values (in particular the default trust settings).

Then, "install" this `SecureProtocolSocketFactory` globally for Apache HttpClient 3.x using something like this:

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https",
   (ProtocolSocketFactory)secureProtocolSocketFactory, 443));
```

Comment: Thanks, useful info. So I need to do this: `httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setHost("www.whatever.com", 443, myhttps);` How does one get hold of the httpClient within Axis2 - I've got a org.apache.axis2.client.Stub and ServiceClient, but how do I get hold of the underlying httpClient from these instances?

Comment: I've tried an approach similar to the other post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6469030/420611  But I keep getting this exception regardless of whether I use `EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory` or `StrictSSLProtocolSocketFactory`:  org.apache.commons.ssl.ProbablyBadPasswordException: Probably bad JKS-Key password: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null

Comment: @Sunny, it sounds like a password problem on your keystore. Independently of your `X509KeyManager`, you'll need to be able to load the private key and cert from your keystore once the `alias`. You could look into "wrapping" the default `X509KeyManager` and only override your logic for choosing the alias (you could use [this](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/source/browse/trunk/jsslutils/src/main/java/org/jsslutils/sslcontext/keymanagers/FixedServerAliasKeyManager.java) as a starting point, except for client aliases).

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bruno, much appreciated. However, I just can't shake that exception even with a simple one line call to the constructor. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663358/keystoreexception-no-private-keys-found-in-keystore-with-not-yet-commons-ssl-0